# Uploading to Teams with C# and Powershell

Tags: c#, powershell, office365, microsoft-teams

I'm writing a form that will upload any file in a folder to a Microsoft Teams share. My code already manage to upload the files, but keep showing me the log in form of microsoft 365 for each file, instead asking only the first time.

this is the code:

```
private void Upload()
    {
        Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();
        runspace.Open();

        PowerShell psinstance = PowerShell.Create();
```

```
//fill some vars and connect (once, hopefully)

            psinstance.AddScript("$SharepointURL = '" + LINK-TO-THE-DESIRED-TEAM + "'");
            psinstance.AddScript("$OutPath = '" + SOURCE-DIRECTORY + "'");
            psinstance.AddScript("Connect-PnPOnline -SPOManagementShell -url $SharepointURL -cleartokencache");
```

```
//upload each file in the directory
            psinstance.AddScript("$Files = Get-ChildItem -path $OutPath");
            psinstance.AddScript("foreach ($File in $Files){ Add-PnPFile -Folder '" + DESIRED-CHANNEL-DIRECTORY + "' -Path $File.FullName }");
```

```
//execute the script
            Collection <PSObject> results = psinstance.Invoke();

//get possible errors
            Collection<ErrorRecord> Errors = psinstance.Streams.Error.ReadAll();
```

```
            runspace.Close();
            }
```

The same powershell code, if executed in the powershell console, works like a sharm. This is driving me crazy, can you help me?

Comment: Does it work when you remove the parameter "-cleartokencache"?

Comment: I got to try it right away and I can tell you that it actually works removing it! however now i need a way to clear any previously created token before executing the code, or it will keep whatever it finds :(

Comment: Why don't you use the Microsoft Graph Api?